# ¿Cómo mostrar una lista con hover en CSS?

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando mostrar una lista al mover el mouse sobre un input con la propiedad HOVER en *CSS*, pero no se muestra. Este es mi *HTML*.

Este es mi código:

```css
.inputDeviceClass:hover #navDevicesid{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="inputDeviceClass" placeholder="Devices List" id="inputDevice" readonly></input>

<div class="navDevices" id="navDevicesid" style="display:none">
    <ul class="deviceSelector">111</ul>
    <ul class="deviceSelector">112</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué colocas los elementos de tu lista en etiquetas ul cuando deberías estar usando li para ello dentro de un ul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- Como recomendación no pongas estilos dentro de las etiquetas a menos de que sea muy necesario.

2.- Lo que te recomiendo es que quites el estilo en la etiqueta y le agregues estilos a tu lista con CSS ejemplo:

```
#navDevicesid{
  display:none;
}
```

3.- Y para mostrar cuando hacer hover, te recomiendo que utilices el selector `+` esto seleccionará al hermano adyacente, ejemplo:

```
.inputDeviceClass:hover + #navDevicesid{
  display: block;
}
```

4.- Te muestro un ejemplo práctico.

```css
#navDevicesid{
  display:none;
}

.inputDeviceClass:hover + #navDevicesid{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="inputDeviceClass" placeholder="Devices List" id="inputDevice" readonly></input>

<div class="navDevices" id="navDevicesid" >
    <ul class="deviceSelector">111</ul>
    <ul class="deviceSelector">112</ul>
</div>
```